# Transfer Minecraft world from legacy console to bedrock on PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

On PS4, the [Legacy Console Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Legacy_Console_Edition) of Minecraft still exists for people who owned it before [Bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition) came out, you can launch it from a button on the Bedrock title screen.

In Legacy Console edition it says your worlds are accessible to transferred into the new Bedrock edition, but I can't figure out how to do so.

I know that the ability to transfer worlds from Legacy PS3 edition to Legacy PS4 edition [was removed in April 2020](https://twitter.com/Minecraft/status/1246120839076028416). But none of those sources mention the Legacy PS4 -> Bedrock PS4 path being removed, so it should still be available?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. In the Bedrock edition world select menu, just scroll to the bottom and there will be a secondary sublist with the heading "old worlds", which are the legacy console worlds. They can be loaded into bedrock from there.